# pascal abc сортировка

Tags: pascal, сортировка, pascalabc.net

Пишу программу на *pascal abc*. Язык вижу впервые, знаю ++ и в целом все написал, но вот сортировка пузыриком не идет у меня...

```
var
  a: array of integer; //Массив типа [Int]
  r: integer; // Для размера массива
  Choice: integer; // Для Switch
  q: integer;

//====================================================
function Print(a: array of integer; r: integer): integer;
begin
    writeln('Данные в массиве: ');
    writeln;
    for i: integer := 0 to (r) - 1 do
      begin
          write('[',i + 1,']');
          write(' = ', a[i]);
          writeln;
      end;
    writeln;
    writeln('Вы хотите отсортировать ваш массив ?');
    writeln;
    writeln('[1] - Да');
    writeln('[2] - Нет');
    writeln;
    write('Ваш ответ: ');
    read(Choice);
          //Цикл для ввода данных в массив
         For i: integer :=1 to r-1 do
          For j: integer :=1 to r-i do
            if a[j]>a[j+1] Then Begin
              q:=a[j];
              a[j]:=a[j+1];
              a[j+1]:=q;
            end;

         //writeln;
         for i: integer := 0 to (r) - 1 do
      begin
          write('[',i + 1,']');
          write(' = ', a[i]);
          writeln;
      end;


   // 2:
     // begin

     // end;

     //else write('Ошибка'); // Если не дан правильный ответ

     end;


//====================================================

begin

  //Задаем размер массива
  writeln('Доброго времени суток');
  write('Введите размер массива: ');
  Read(r);

  SetLength(a, r); //Функция для динамического массива
  randomize; //Функция для создания рандомных чисел


  //Чтоб текст не шел cплашмя, делаем отступ
  writeln(' ');

  writeln('[1] - Вручную заполнить массив данными');
  writeln('[2] - Автоматический ввод данных в массив');

  writeln(' ');

  //Работаем со Switch (от нашего выбора зависит по какой ветке пойдет Switch)
  write('Введите желаемое действие: ');
  read(Choice);

  writeln(' ');
           //Цикл для ввода данных в массив
        for i: integer := 0 to Length(a) - 1 do
          begin
            a[i] := random(1000);
          end;

        writeln(' ');
        Print(a,r);

end.
```

Попробовал разные способы, но увы не получается, 
выдает ошибку:

> Program1.pas(29) : Ошибка времени выполнения: Индекс находился вне
>   границ массива.

Comment: В паскале массив индексируется с 1, а не с 0

Comment: Не подскажите решение для моего случая  ? У меня не выходит ничего =\

Comment: Не выдумывайте. Массивы индексируются либо с 0, либо как указать вручную. Вероятно вы перепутали с индексацией символов в строке?

Comment: Индексация с 0 — это стереотип привитый преподавателями.
А этим преподавателям — их преподавателями ;–)

Comment: @Jurii добро пожаловать в мир программирования, где индексация с 0 более удобна, чем с 1 ;-) Я сам раньше с 1 индексировал, и последние года 3 до сих пор продолжаю переводить старый код на индексацию с 0. Она реально удобнее.

Comment: @Jurii, Анрей  PascalABC.NET компилирует под .net. В .net, в отличии от классической турбы, индексация от 0. Т.е. может конкретный язык и пытается сделать индексацию с 1, но это совершенно чужно для его платформы. Поэтому статика еще пытается инексироваться с 1, но динамика следует правилам платформы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по коду, вы пишите на PascalABC.NET…
Тогда вот так:

```
procedure Sort(var a : array of Integer);
begin
  for var i := 1 to a.Length-1 do
    for var j := a.Length-1 downto i do
      if A[j - 1] > A[j] then
        Swap(A[j - 1], A[j]);
end;

procedure manualArray(n : Integer);
begin
  var a : array of Integer;
  SetLength(a, n);
  for var i := 0 to n-1 do
    a[i] := ReadLnInteger('a[' + (i+1) + '] =');
  WriteLn('Введённый массив: ', a);
  Sort(a);
  WriteLn('Отсортированный массив: ', a);
end;

procedure randomArray(n : Integer);
begin
  var a := ArrRandomInteger(n, -10, +10);
  WriteLn('Заполненный массив: ', a);
  Sort(a);
  WriteLn('Отсортированный массив: ', a);
end;

begin
  WriteLn('Доброго времени суток!', NewLine);
  var n := ReadLnInteger('Введите размер массива: n =');
  WriteLn(NewLine, 'Выберите способ заполнения массива:', NewLine,
  '  [1] - вручную', NewLine, '  [2] - случайными числами');
  case ReadLnInteger('Ваш выбор:') of
    1 : manualArray(n);
    2 : randomArray(n);
  end;
end.
```

P.S. Если процедуру Sort закомментировать или вообще убрать, то программа всё равно будет работать ;–)

Comment: Спасибо :) работает, сейчас попробую изучить и понять что я делал не так) на ++ спокойно сделал... паскаль впервые вижу, посмотрел на синтаксис и начал писать) но вот сортировка чет меня как-то не поддалась :D

Comment: Вы сортировали немного неправильно.
У меня в процедуре sort применён классический вид обменной сортировки в общем употреблении „пузырьковой“.